# How can I cut internet-access for a single process momentarily

Tags: networking, internet

I am running an application on an Ubuntu server. It is connecting to an external service over TCP.

Sometimes, the external service seems to be down or not responding. In this case, my program shows very weird behaviour. I would like to debug it, however since this happens very rarely it is not easy to induce this situation. I had the idea that I could cut the internet access of my program manually. However, it has to run a few minutes before I do it. I also cannot shut down the whole network interface since I do not have physical access to the server and would thus loose the SSH-Connection.

How can I quickly turn internet access on and off for a single, running process?

Comment: Since the TCP connection appears to the program as a "socket" (see `man 2 socket`), structurally, there's no easy way to interrupt and reestablish a connection. Perhaps, you could put the connection through a local server that you could stop and start. Replace `TCP:External.Service.com:port` with `TCP:localhost:otherport`, and have the server (simple Perl script) forward packets to `TCP:External.Service.com:port`, if you have access to the source or configuration.